# Django query with many to many and through table

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

**Lets suppose i have these Django ORM classes:**

```
class Event(models.Model):
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="created_events")
    participants = models.ManyToManyField(
        User, related_name="joined_events", through='EventsParticipants')


class EventsParticipants(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
    date_invited = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now_add=True, blank=False, null=False)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('user', 'event'),)

class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(....)
```

**My question is:**
I want to get all the events created by me + all the events that I'm participated in using the Event class, in a single query set.

Comment: You should take some time and write the correct question with the actual code instead editing it and making people lose time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
from django.db.models import Q

Event.objects.filter(Q(creator=me) | Q(participants=me)).distinct()
```

See:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects
https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct

Comment: This will give me a duplicate results if there is a two or more EventsParticipants row with the same event_id and with a different user_id

Comment: also note that  user and event in the EventsParticipants are unique_together, I'v updated the question to reflect that

Comment: have you tried it?  it seems to me if you have the `unique_together` defined then the only duplicate result you will get is for an event where you are both the creator and a participant on the same event... if you expect that to happen you might be better off doing it in two querysets, one as creator and one `Event.objects.exclude(creator=me).filter(participants=me)`

Comment: Yes I'v tried it again with a new Django project, when i add 5 rows in EventsParticipants with the same event_id and with 5 different users, it will return the same Event object 5 times.

Comment: oh, I think it needs a call to `.distinct()` on the end, see updated answer